# Mysql replicate-rewrite-db not working

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication

Been "slaving" on this issue all day.

I have a master/slave setup that works, but when I try to replicate to a different database name on the slave it fails.  This is what my.cnf looks like:

```
server-id=101
report-host=Slave01

replicate_do_db='DB1'
replicate-rewrite-db=DB1->DB2

replicate-ignore-table=DB2.SOME_TABLE_NAME
```

If I take out the replicate-rewrite-db line, it works perfectly and replicates the DB1 database from the master to the slave.
The master log position I am using on the slave is after the CREATE DATABASE DB1 call on the master.  After that log position, the tables are created and data imported on the master.
I don't configure and start the slave until after I create the DB2 database.

Any ideas?

Update: Saw this in the mysql error log:

```
120531 15:48:19 [Note] Slave I/O thread: connected to master 'slave_user@master_server:3306',  replication started in log 'mysql-bin.000001' at position 107
120531 15:48:20 [ERROR] Slave: Error 'Unknown database 'DB1'' on query. Default database: 'DB1'. Query: 'CREATE TABLE `ANOTHER_TABLE` (
```

Comment: +1 on the question as well because I am sure you are not the first one to have this situation based on mixing replication filters.

Answer (score 7):

I received a hint in a comment but the user has since deleted it.

The trick is to not use replicate-do-db and only use replicate-rewrite-db:

```
#replicate_do_db='DB1'
replicate-rewrite-db=DB1->DB2
```

Commenting out the replicate_do_db line in my.cnf fixed it for me.

Thanks to the mystery user who pointed me in the right direction, whoever you are.

Comment: I may just be guessing on this one, but if database DB1 did not exist on the Slave, that's probably why you got that error. You could have ran `CREATE DATABASE db1;` on the Slave and restarted replication . That would probably have solved it as well, but your solution is actually simpler and does not require a dummy database. +1 !!!

Comment: The only problem I'm seeing now is that the tables from the master.mysql are replicating into slave.DB2.  I'm pretty sure I can filter them out though.

Answer (score 1):

An important note:
You must to add the name of rewrited database. Add this line in your my.cnf:

```
replicate-do-db=DB2
```

So your config file must be like this finally:

```
server-id=101
report-host=Slave01

replicate_do_db       =  DB2
replicate-rewrite-db  =  DB1->DB2

replicate-ignore-table=DB2.SOME_TABLE_NAME
```

I tested it and it works